# Changing UILabel over time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, time, uilabel

I have a simple UILabel on that I want to change the text of every 10 seconds. What is the best way of doing this, which let's the rest of the interface remain active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
self.repeatingTimer = timer;
...

- (void) updateLabel:(id)sender {
    myLabel.text = newStringValue;
}

...
[repeatingTimer invalidate];
self.repeatingTimer = nil; // stops timer
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to start an NSTimer and update the label.text each time.